# Javascript - Print Html Content not apply all CSS properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf

I have implemented a print function that allow the user to print a portion of a page.

This is the code:

```
print(): void {
    let printContents, popupWin;
    printContents = document.getElementById('print-section').innerHTML;
    popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto');
    popupWin.document.open();
    popupWin.document.write(`
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>Print tab</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MegaMark - Reporting App</title>


  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" media='print,screen' type='text/css' href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" media='print,screen' type='text/css' href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" media='print,screen' type='text/css' href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" media='print,screen' type='text/css' href="./plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" media='print,screen' type='text/css' href="./distAdminLte2/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" media='print,screen' type='text/css' href="./distAdminLte2/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" media='print,screen' type="text/css" href="./node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" media='print,screen' type="text/css" href="./node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
        </head>
    <body onload="window.print();">${printContents}</body>
      </html>`
    );
    popupWin.document.close();
}
```

The function runs properly, It open a new window with the **content properly rendered**.

The problem is that when I save the content as PDF file using "Microsoft print to PDF" as printer or "PDF Creator" , the PDF is not applying all the css properly...

I don't know if it is an angular problem or css problem...

Thanks to support

Comment: have you tried to wrap your `window.print()` in a `setTimeout()` at the end of the doc? perhaps all of the resources are not yet loaded?

Comment: Yes, I have already tried but it didn't fix the problem